# How to declare a variable in a ternary expression?

Tags: javascript, scope, ternary-operator, variable-declaration

I need to set `i` depending on a condition:

```
let i = null
nightmode === true ? i = 1 : i = 0
```

Is it possible to declare `i` within the ternary expression, or does it have to be in outside of it (to handle scoping)?

Comment: Your ternary is using a side effect instead of how it was designed to be used. `let i = nightmode === true ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the ternary directly as assignment for the value.

```
let i = nightmode === true ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable `i` needs to be outside of it, although it is possible to set `i` in the following manner:

```js
let nightmode = true;
let i = (nightmode === true) ? 1 : 0
console.log(i);
```